# Слитно или раздельно писать "не"?

Tags: орфография

"...на не(?)облагаемую налогом сумму".

Comment: Если считаете ответ правильным, пожалуйста, одобрите его (нажмите на галочку справа от ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Раздельно, так как есть уточняющее слово.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это полное причастие с зависимым словом, поэтому раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

Раздельно.